# App not working from start menu in windows 7 XP mode

Tags: windows-7

We have an application developed with Oracle forms that is not compatible with Windows 7, so we are trying to make it run in XP mode. The app needs to be run from a domain account. So i have created the virtual machine and joined it in the domain. Now, i start the virtual machine, log in wit my domain accont and the app works fine. The problem appears when i try to start it directly from the windows 7 start menu link.The virtual machine ask me for credentials, i log in but the app throws an error like if i was not using a domain account. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Can you show me the error please?

Comment: The error is thrown by the app  so i dont think it can help you, but it occurs when it is run by a user not in the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found the solution. To publish the app in windows 7 start menu, i had to copy its shortcut to All users\Programs and that was the problem. Now, i have created a batch calling the shortcut in my user desktop and copy it in All users\Programs. That makes the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Start -> Run -> type in: `control keymgr.dll` and hit Enter.
```

Add your application and credentials there and test it again.

Comment: I have added the network resource where the app is and still not working but i have noticed that i can't ping the resource, altough i can browse through it, so maybe there is a DNS problem.

Comment: Are you trying to ping the hostname or the IP? Is it possible that a firewall is enabled there?

Comment: Ping is working now, firewall is disabled by policy. Also, I have been looking in event viewer (both vm and host) and no errors related.